# DEVEXPRESS DASHBOARD CONNECTİON STRİNG PROBLEM

Tags: devexpress, cross-platform, connection-string, dashboard, xaf

I am working with devexpress xaf and I have an problem with dashboards. I am creating dashboard without any problem but everytime when I try to join or edit dashboard, it is given me connection error. I am rejoin to database to join dashboard.

[This is error which I get. I am choosing SQL server here and I am joining dashboard. But it is so annoying.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyTAq.png)

I changed xml file and fixed this but after I changed something and save it xml turning back old format. In the other hand, I am  writing my sql server name and password to xml and it is not look like good idea. Please inform me If you have any idea to help me!

[This is my dashboard page After I joined connection string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRAt3.png)

Best regards,
Yakup

I am trying to create dashboard with XAF app. There is no problem expect everytime I try to open or edit dashboard, it give me connection error. Bu I want to arrange one time that connection. After than it must remember that informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem over a year ago.

I found this link helping me out:

[How to: Provide Credentials for the Dashboards Module when Using External Data Sources](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t473885/how-to-provide-credentials-for-the-dashboards-module-when-using-external-data-sources)

Somewhere half way the page you find the caption:
*Also, if you don't plan to view these dashboards on the Web, you can enable saving credentials in a database in the following manner (you need to add this to YourSolution.Module.Win\Controllers  folder):*